# memory allocation in c when casting returned value to pointer

Tags: c, memory-management

In c,
when defining a variable like `int a; int* b;`, memory is allocated in stack.
When using malloc, heap memory is used.

My question is, if in a function like the one below:

```
void* function () {
int counter = 0;
while() {
   ... does some counting
   counter++;
}
return (void *) counter;
}
```

It is returning a pointer to counter, where does the memory of counter live? The code segment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C function memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406576/c-function-memory-allocation)

Comment: It is not returning a pointer to `counter`.   It is converting the value of `counter` to a `void *`.      That will be an invalid pointer, in the sense that any usage of it gives undefined behaviour.   So it doesn't have to "live" anywhere in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not returning a pointer to `counter`. That would be `&counter`, which is a pointer to a local variable. Doing that would be an error because local variables are destroyed as soon as the function returns, so the caller would be left with a pointer to a thing that no longer exists.

In practice, `counter` probably lives on the stack or in a register (or several registers). The code segment is usually read-only, so variables couldn't live there.

`(void *)counter` is converting a number to a pointer value. The results of that operation are implementation-defined.

For example, with [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html):

> A cast from integer to pointer discards most-significant bits if the pointer representation is smaller than the integer type, extends according to the signedness of the integer type if the pointer representation is larger than the integer type, otherwise the bits are unchanged.

The resulting address may not be a valid pointer value at all, or it may point to an unmapped page.

Comment: (void*) 1 is just an example, lemme change it to something to make more sense

Comment: the code definitely compiles, this is how pthread_join and pthread_exit work.

Comment: @JunbangHuang I said `&1` does not compile.

Comment: The definition of "undefined" in the standard includes many things, including "no diagnostic required".